# Difference of print and return in R?

Tags: r

I have defined a factorial function. The script goes like this:

```
fac <- function(x) {
  f=1
  for (i in 1:x) {
    f = f * i
    print(f)
  }
  print(f)
}
```

If fac(5), then the output looks like this :

```
[1] 1
[1] 2
[1] 6
[1] 24
[1] 120
[1] 720
[1] 5040
```

But when I change the 'print(f)' parts into 'return(f)' the output is :

```
[1] 1
```

Why does this happen? Is there a difference between print and return in R?

Answer (score 7):

Let's try by example:

```
fac <- function(x) {
  f=1
  for (i in 1:x) {
    f = f * i
    print(f)
  }
  print(f)
}

fac2 <- function(x) {
  f=1
  for (i in 1:x) {
    f = f * i
    print(f)
  }
  return(f)
}

fac3 <- function(x) {
  f=1
  for (i in 1:x) {
    f = f * i
    return(f)
  }
  print(f)
}
```

And use them:

```
> f1 <- fac(10)
[1] 1
[1] 2
[1] 6
[1] 24
[1] 120
[1] 720
[1] 5040
[1] 40320
[1] 362880
[1] 3628800
[1] 3628800
> f2 <- fac2(10)
[1] 1
[1] 2
[1] 6
[1] 24
[1] 120
[1] 720
[1] 5040
[1] 40320
[1] 362880
[1] 3628800
> f3 <- fac3(10)
> f1
[1] 3628800
> f2
[1] 3628800
> f3
[1] 1
```

`print` as it names implies print to the console (and return the value printed)

`return` only return the value and ends the function.

In the case of `fac(10)`, the last `print` is the last value of `f`, and it returns it, as `fac2(10)` does with the difference it does not print it twice as there's only the `print` in the loop printing the value.

`fac3(10)` return at the first iteration, hence it does never go to the `print` statement and return the first value without printing anything to console.

What you can do for this is:

```
fixedfac <- function(x) {
  f=vector('numeric',x) # pre allocate the return vector to avoid copy while growing in the loop
  tmp=1 # use a temp var for the maths (could be avoided, but it's to keep it simple)
  for (i in 1:x) {
    tmp <- tmp * i # do the math
    f[i] <- tmp # store in result
  }
  f # return the vector with all values (we need at least this as for does not return anything).
}
```

Which will return a vector (`return` is unnecessary as a function always return the value of its last statement)

```
> fixedfac(10)
 [1]       1       2       6      24     120     720    5040   40320  362880 3628800
```

Comment: Good answer! It may be worth noting that `print` is a generic function in R, whereas `return` is not. What `print` passes on to the console depends on the class of object to which it is applied, and the printed content may be different from the return value (i.e., the fact that `print` also returns invisibly does not always mean that it "prints it twice" as you put it). Moreover, `return` can only be called from within a function, whereas `print` will run pretty much everywhere.

Comment: @SimonG What I mean when I said it print it twice is in fac1 there's the print call in the loop and the print call at end of the function, hence printing twice, in fac2 as we have a return instead of print it does not print twice.

Comment: @SimonG And at this point I could write a complete book with subtleties of both print and return, would be too long for an answer :) I hope I give enough clues for readers to dig in the doc of both :)

Comment: Yeah, I got that. The difference is subtle of course, because even the return value will be "printed" using a `print` method. However, I felt that it's worth pointing this out.

Comment: @SimonG I completed my sentence on the answer to avoid ambiguity, I was not talking about the invisibility state of the return value of `print`, digging this way sounds far too much in my opinion :)

Answer (score 0):

Of course there is a difference between `print` and `return`. From R documentation: "`print` prints its argument and returns it invisibly (via `invisible(x)`)." So it prints value to console and return it. At the same time `return` function's base responsibility is returning value. And if it isn't assigned to variable it goes to console.

So when you replace `print`  to `return` your function brakes on `return` with value and not running further.

Try to assign value to some variable to see the difference
`a <- fac(5)`

Answer (score 0):

In R print takes the value you provide it and determines how it will print the items in that variable to the command line, its to see the values in the variable.  Return will return the value back to the caller of the function but that value must be either stored in a variable or can be piped straight into another function.

```
fac <- function(x) {
  f=1
  for (i in 1:x) {
    f = f * i
    print(f)
  }
  return(f)
}
```

fac(10) worked just fine and yielded 3628800

Comment: Or perhaps OP just replaced all `print` statements with `return` statements  ? (hence stopping at first iteration...)